# В DictType могут быть использованы только ассоциативные массивы

Tags: python, requests, discord

пытаюсь сделать скрипт чтоб при запуске с помощью токена дискорд, кидался запрос в друзья по ID, но столкнулся с капчей, решил использовать библиотеку 2captcha-python, написал решение капчи, получил код для прохождения капчи, передал этот код в пейлоад, но в итоге выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
({'message': 'Некорректная форма основного текста', 'code': 50035, 'errors': {'_errors': [{'code': 'DICT_TYPE_CONVERT', 'message': 'В DictType могут быть использованы только ассоциативные массивы'}]}}, 400)
```

Как это можно исправить? Заранее спасибо!

**Код:**

```
import requests
import json
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha


with open("config.json") as file:
    config = json.load(file)

def send_friend_request(token, userid, proxy):
    solver = TwoCaptcha(config["CAPTCHA_TOKEN"])
    headers = {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'Authorization': token,
        'Content-Length': '2',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Origin': 'https://discord.com',
        'Referer': 'https://discord.com/channels/858779728467197952/1136301972375478412',
        'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"',
        'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
        'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': "Windows",
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'User-Agent': UserAgent().random,
        'X-Context-Properties': 'eyJsb2NhdGlvbiI6IlVzZXIgUHJvZmlsZSJ9',
        'X-Debug-Options': 'bugReporterEnabled',
        'X-Super-Properties': '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'
}

    cookie = {
        'Cookie': '__dcfduid=7d175f0006f211eeb92afdc7cf1d397d; __sdcfduid=7d175f0106f211eeb92afdc7cf1d397d836df0c2a172a010cdc96be5619b2f39aa36c6d68c099221df436338f14059be; _gcl_au=1.1.1317996987.1686334833; _ga=GA1.1.360061260.1686334833; __cfruid=afa55739bc9ab0351ffed6fb8a2ca043ff53d714-1691402303; locale=ru; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Mon+Aug+07+2023+12%3A57%3A24+GMT%2B0300+(%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)&version=6.33.0&hosts=&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false; cf_clearance=1nMTLWZGVcaA.Lg6QIwxgkyNCeRcwO.GGW5quK2tXvc-1691402304-0-1-d17d8921.1dbc0165.867cd6c1-0.2.1691402304; _ga_Q149DFWHT7=GS1.1.1691402244.24.0.1691402244.0.0.0'
    }

    url = f'https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/relationships/{userid}'


    r1 = requests.put(url=url, headers=headers, json={}, cookies=cookie)
    response = solver.hcaptcha(sitekey=json.loads(r1.text)["captcha_sitekey"], url=url)

    payload = [{"captcha_key": response["code"]}]

    r = requests.put(url=url, headers=headers, json=payload, cookies=cookie)
    return r.json(), r.status_code
```